Flutter app - Screen orientation is not locked when system notification is showing
I'm working on an application that required the screen orientation is landscape locked. But whenever the system notification is showing, I still be able to rotate the screen orientation to portrait. For example, the notification about "Allow app to find, connet to nearby device" or "Do you want to update this app".
notification example
I already used these code to lock the app orientation in Flutter:
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);

And add these code in  tag of AndroidManifest.xml file:
android:screenOrientation="landscape"

And try these code on MainActivity.java file:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
    }

How can I lock the screen orientation even when a system notification is showing?
Thank for making a read!!
